# How to generate dependency files when generating object files of c sources with make

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I am implementing a build system using the GNU tools, GCC and make to compile multiple targets, link them together and create a final executable. All these support two platforms; the host environment and the embedded system MSP432.

I am taking an introductory course on embedded systems and doing an assignment that I am fighting with some days ago. I was trying by myself reading over the internet, also reading here in stackoverflow  but I don’t get it yet, I am still a rookie on this, so I hope someone can explain me or giving me a hint about how to fix the issue

As said, the build system must support the two platforms so at first step, I focus on making sure all works for the host environment.

### In the makefile I have created rules for the following targets:

1. `build`         - Generates executable file, object files, dependency files and map file
2. `%.o: %.c` ...  - Generates object files and its dependencies
3. `compile-all`       - Compiles all objects but do not link them
4. `%.i: %.c`      - Generates preprocessed output of C source files
5. `%.asm: %.C`        - Generates assembly output of C source files
6. `clean`         - Clean all generated files

### The issue is when executing `make build PLATFORM=HOST`

Running the command, we get:

```
.../src$ sudo make build PLATFORM=HOST
gcc -Wall -Werror -g -std=c99 -DHOST -Wl,-O0,-Map=c1m2.map main.c memory.c -I../includes/common -o c1m2.out
make: *** No rule to make target 'main.o', needed by 'build'.  Stop.
```

I notice that the error comes because the line 132 were we have

```
%.o: %.c
```

This line is intended for disabling the built-in rule and using the user defined one that comes next line, but it is not doing it, so I try commenting this line and executing the build again and we get:

```
.../src$ sudo make build PLATFORM=HOST
gcc -Wall -Werror -g -std=c99 -DHOST -Wl,-O0,-Map=c1m2.map main.c memory.c -I../includes/common -o c1m2.out
gcc -Wall -Werror -g -std=c99 -DHOST -E  -c -o main.o main.c
main.c:23:22: fatal error: platform.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
< builtin >: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Now it says that it does not find “platform.h” despite it being indicated by the INCLUDES variable that contains the location of the header file. Also,  it is using the built-in recipe for generating the object files and fails.

So I am stuck at this point, the idea is building the output executable, the map file, the object files and its dependencies files when executing “make build PLATFORM=HOST”.

At the beginning I wrote the build target just for generating the output, the map and object files and did work and then after doing the modifications for generating the dependency files I got lost with this error.

The other recipes for generating preproceessed files, assembly files and doing a clean were working ok.

### You can clone the folder with all the needed files from: https://github.com/Fornaso/C1M2.git

Thank you all in advance.

Here is my Makefile:

`#******************************************************************************
# Copyright (C) 2017 by Alex Fosdick - University of Colorado
#
# Redistribution, modification or use of this software in source or binary
# forms is permitted as long as the files maintain this copyright. Users are 
# permitted to modify this and use it to learn about the field of embedded
# software. Alex Fosdick and the University of Colorado are not liable for any
# misuse of this material. 
#
#******************************************************************************

# Modified on April 2020 by Adrián Fornaso

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Simple Makefile for multitarget build system
#
# Use: make [TARGET] [PLATFORM-OVERRIDES]
#
# Build Targets:
#
# build                 - Builds and links all source files and genereates:
#
#                       c1m2.map - Map file for the full build
#                       *.d      - Dependency Files for each source file
#                       *.o      - Individual object files
#                       c1m2.out - Output Executable file
#
#<FILE>.i               - Builds <FILE>.i preprocessed file.
#<FILE>.asm             - Builds <FILE>.i assembly file.
#<FILE>.o               - Builds <FILE>.o object file.
#compile-all            - Compile all objects but do NOT link them.
#clean                  - Removes all generated files.
#
# Platform Overrides: Conditionally assign the appropriate compiler flags,
#                     linker flags, and architecture flags. The target platform
#                     must be provided at the command line with the make
#                     command to set the platform you are compiling for.
#       
#                     PLATFORM = MSP432 - The target embedded system will use
#                                         the cross compiler, arm-none-eabi-gcc.
#                     PLATFORM = HOST   - The host embedded system will use the
#                                         native compiler, gcc.
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#General Flags (Both Platforms)
#
#   -Wall           Enable All Warning Messages (CFLAGS)
#   -Werror         Treats All Warnings as Errors(CFLAGS)
#   -g              Generate Debugging Info in Executable (CFLAGS)
#   -O0             The level of optimization (-O0, -O1, -O2, -O3)) (LDFLAGS)
#   -std=c99        The C standard set (CFLAGS)
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Target name
BASENAME = c1m2
TARGET = $(BASENAME).out

#General Flags
COMMONCFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -g -std=c99
COMMONLDFLAGS = -Wl,-O0,-Map=$(BASENAME).map
#No spaces after commas after -Wl option.

CPPFLAGS = -E
# -E flag makes the compiler stop in the preprocessed output

#Compile time switches
ifeq ($(PLATFORM), MSP432)
    INCLUDES =  -I../includes/common    \
                -I../includes/msp432    \
                -I../includes/CMSIS
    SOURCES =   main.c                          \
                memory.c                        \
                interrupts_msp432p401r_gcc.c    \
                startup_msp432p401r_gcc.c       \
                system_msp432p401r.c

    LINKER_FILE = msp432p401r.lds
    CPU = cortex-m4
    ARCH = armv7e-m
    SPECS = nosys.specs

    CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
    LD = arm-none-eabi-ld

    LDFLAGS = $(COMMONLDFLAGS), -T=$(LINKER_FILE)

    CFLAGS =    $(COMMONCFLAGS) -D$(PLATFORM) -mcpu=$(CPU)  \
                        -march=$(ARCH) --specs=$(SPECS)
    OBJDUMP = arm-none-eabi-objdump
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM), HOST)
    INCLUDES = -I../includes/common

    SOURCES =   main.c  \
                memory.c

    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDFLAGS = $(COMMONLDFLAGS)
    CFLAGS = $(COMMONCFLAGS) -D$(PLATFORM)
    OBJDUMP = objdump
endif

#Listing object files:
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

# 1. --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Complete build:        c1m2.map - Map file for the full build
#                        *.d      - Dependency Files for each source file
#                        *.o      - Individual object files
#                        c1m2.out - Output Executable file

# LDFLAGS contains the flags for creating the *.map file

.PHONY: build
build: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
$(TARGET):
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(SOURCES) $(INCLUDES) -o $@


# 2. --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# //// Generates the object files of all c-program implementation files and its
#      dependecies. ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#This implementation places dependency files into a subdirectory named .deps.
DEPDIR := .deps
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.d

# Delete the built-in rules for building object files from .c files, so that
# our rule is used instead.
#%.o: %.c
# Our rule for building object files with its dependency
%.o: %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d | $(DEPDIR)
    $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $^

# Declare a rule for creating the dependency directory if it doesn’t exist.
$(DEPDIR): ; @mkdir -p $@

# Generate a list of all the dependency files that could exist.
DEPFILES := $(SRCS:%.c=$(DEPDIR)/%.d)

# Mention each dependency file as a target, so that make won’t fail if the file
# doesn’t exist.
$(DEPFILES):


# 2 bis. ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# /// Generates the object file of all c-program implementation files. ////////
#%.o: %.c
#   $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $^


# 3. --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /// Compile all objects but do NOT link them. ///////////////////////////////
.PHONY: compile-all
compile-all: $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $^


# 4. --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /// Generates the preprocessed output of all c-program implementation files. 
%.i: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $^    


# 5. --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /// Create assembler file of a C source. ////////////////////////////////////
%.asm: %.c
    $(CC) -S $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@
# -S flag tells the compiler just generate the assembly file


# 6. --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /// Removes all compiled objects, preprocessed outputs, assembly outputs,
#     executable files and build output files. ////////////////////////////////
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET) $(BASENAME).map *.asm *.i
    rm -r .dep

#End of file`

Comment: regarding: `COMMONCFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -g -std=c99`  This would be much better written as: `COMMONCFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wconverson -pedantic -Werror -g -std=c99`   Notice the extra options to enable the warnings and the use of `:=` so the macro is only evaluated once.

Comment: regarding: `CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDFLAGS = $(COMMONLDFLAGS)
    CFLAGS = $(COMMONCFLAGS) -D$(PLATFORM)
    OBJDUMP = objdump`  Strongly suggest using `:=` rather than `=` so the macros are only evaluated once

Comment: the linker processes parameters from left to right, so the list of object files should be before any library file references

Comment: regarding: `%.o: %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d | $(DEPDIR)
    $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $^`  strongly suggest breaking this into two rules, one to create the dependency file and one to perform the compile

Comment: I will do those modifications. Now I started checking the build for the embedded MSP432 platform and I am looking for how to use the linker file, cause make file and source files are inside the src folder meanwhile the linker file is outside the src folder and the build does not find it.

Comment: user3629249, how we can create the dependency files without compiling the object files. I was trying to do it in that way, in two steps, at the beginning. In the Makefile there are some comented lines for generating the compiled object in one step but, I havent arrived to produce the dependencies in other step apart so, I commented them  and did all in one step cause I found that explanation on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two small mistakes which took me quite a while to see:

- `DEPFILES := $(SRCS:%.c=$(DEPDIR)/%.d)` has to be `DEPFILES := $(SOURCES:%.c=$(DEPDIR)/%.d)` - otherwise `DEPFILES` is empty since `SRCS` is undefined.
- In `$(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $^` the `$^` (*all the prerequisites*) expands to e. g. `main.c .deps/main.d`, so a not yet existing `.deps/main.d` is passed as an input file; we want `$*.c` instead of `$^`.

Another minor error is:

- `rm -r .dep` should be `rm -r .deps` or `rm -r $(DEPDIR)`.

Comment: More traditional than `$*.c` is to use`$<` which expands to the first prerequisite.

Comment: Thank you Armali and MadScienist, I corrected the code using what you said and now it is producing the dependencies in the _.deps_ folder as desired.  Executing the build we get all the generated files. Now I notice something when I run the _clean target_ with _make_; we can't delete the generated files, listing them we see they appear with `-rw-r--r--` rights but, with _root as owner name_ and _root as owner group_.  Do you recommend changing the rights adding the commands in the _clean target recipe_ or is there a cleaner way for that, like generating the files with user rights already?

Comment: I noticed why, the clean target was having this behavior; it was because I was executing `make clean` instead `make clean PLATFORM=HOST`. If the way code is written, we need to specify the platform for the switches work, cause variables and flags that are defined inside the platform switches, that is the case of the SOURCES variable than later is used for listing objects inside the variable OBJECTS. It is not that clean wasn't deleting files cause rights, it was because the command `rm -f $(OBJECTS) ... was having OBJECTS variable empty when doing `make clean`.